# Building a Flutter web app while being connected to the internet gives me an internal server error.?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome-devtools, android-studio-3.0, flutter-web

When I run my flutter web project in a debug version of Chrome while being connected to internet, I get the following build message:

> Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
>
> Building application for the web...
>
> Attempting to connect to browser instance..
>
> Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55339/mh67GZ3e4D0=

Which probably means that the website is hosted locally with port 55339.

But the chrome windows is opened with the port 55063 and which is completely blank.

[image: Blank Screen with port 55063]

When I try to open "127.0.0.1:55339", which supposedly should open my web project gives me an error:
`Internal Server Error`

But when I disconnect from Internet and build the project , Project builds successfully and executes perfectly, as in the proper window is opened.

What could possibly go wrong while I am connected to internet, something related to proxy?

**How do I build the project while still being connected to internet?**

Answer (score 1):

**try to run with this command:** `flutter run --release -d chrome -v`

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's useful to include an explanation.